# Teradata BTEQ and TPT alternative in Snowflake

Tags: teradata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to figure out what are the alternatives in Snowflake for Teradata BTEQ's and TPT(Import/Export)

In Teradata BTEQ's, which are run for an Enterprise using scheduled jobs on UNIX/LINUX , we have the flexibility of writing different SQL's in a sequence.

What alternative we have in Snowflake?

Comment: To help those people unfamiliar with Teradata (but who know Snowflake), it would probably just be easier if you explain the functionality that you want to implement in Snowflake

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar with Terdata but based on [this overview of beteq](https://docs.teradata.com/r/jmAxXLdiDu6NiyjT6hhk7g/root) I would say that the Snowflake equivalent is probably the [SnowSQL CLI](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql.html). In terms of import/export the SnowSQL CLI can be used to upload data via the [PUT command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html#put).

Comment: Do we have any sample SnowSql script which performs connection to Snowflake and executes from DML statements along with error handling maybe.